# Rust espressif Thread

Tags: rust, embedded, esp32

Working on Rust espressif, I'm looking to control the LED on my esp32-c3-devkit-rust. I am setting up a server which in a POST request must flash an LED (led on led off).
Below is my piece of code where in a thread, I call the led_task function which in a loop takes care of the functionality.
I have 2 questions:
. How can I return an HTTP response while a loop exist ?
. How can I interrupt the thread and restart a new one during a new POST? (case where I ask to change color)

```
server.fn_handler("/settings", Method::Post, move |mut request| {
        let mut resp = request.into_ok_response()?;
        if let Ok(form) = serde_json::from_slice::<UserSettings>(&buf) {

            let handle = thread::spawn({
                let _my_led = temp_led.clone();
                let _my_struct = form.clone();
                move || {
                    led_task(_my_led, _my_struct);                                                                    
                }
            });
            handle.join().unwrap();
            write!(
                resp,
                "led on with red {}-blue {}-green {}!",
                form.red, form.blue, form.green
            )?;
        } else {
            resp.write_all("JSON error".as_bytes())?;
        }
}

fn led_task(led: Arc<Mutex<WS2812RMT<'_>>>, data: UserSettings) {
    let ws2812 = led.clone();
    // mode is on flashing or not
    if data.mode {
        loop {
            ws2812
            .lock()
            .unwrap()
            .set_pixel(RGB8::new(
                0
                , 0
                , 0))
            .unwrap();
            FreeRtos::delay_ms(data.delay);
            println!("led task loop ...");
            ws2812
            .lock()
            .unwrap()
            .set_pixel(RGB8::new(
                data.red
                , data.green
                , data.blue))
            .unwrap();
            FreeRtos::delay_ms(data.delay);
        }
    } else {
        ws2812
        .lock()
        .unwrap()
        .set_pixel(RGB8::new(
            data.red
            , data.green
            , data.blue))
        .unwrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi all, I'm sorry. Just a newbie who misunderstood everything. So I close